# Angular - A mat tab group is two way binded to an array in the typescript. How to switch to viewing a certain mat- tab via typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

Code can be seen below.

So I have a mat tab group where a mat tab exists for each ValidationStep object in the validationSteps[] in the typescript via two way binding. So if i add anothet element to the array, a new tab is added to the front end.

I have functionality from the front to add a object to the array which generates a new tab. How can I then simulate a user clicking the tab to view it?

component

```
export class AddEditControlComponent {

validationSteps: ValidationStep[];

 addDocumentStepButtonClick():{
//create validationStep object and add it to array

}
}
```

Html template. There is a button to add a validationStep

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex">



            <mat-tab disabled>
                    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                        <button  (click)="addDocumentStepButtonClick()">
                            Add Document Step
                        </button>
                    </ng-template>
                </mat-tab>

 <div *ngFor="let step of validationSteps; let i = index ">

//mat tab for each validationStep

  </div>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you have to  set `selectedTabIndex` to corresponding index

Answer (score 0):

You can check : [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jrqknmdoydg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.ts)